# $P(X=0)=1$ does not implies $X(\omega)=0 \forall \,\, \omega \in \Omega$

Tags: probability

Why does $P(X=0)=1$ does not implies $X(\omega)=0 \forall \,\, \omega \in \Omega$?
I just want to confirm that my counterexample proof it. 
Suppose $\Omega = (0,1)$. If X map all point except for finite number of point to $0$ than we would have $P(X=0)=1$ but this does not implies $X(\omega)=0 \forall \,\, \omega \in \Omega$. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, your example is correct.

Comment: Does $\omega\in\omega$ mean $\omega\in\Omega$?

Comment: oh yes sorry, thanks for the answer